# Kivy Raspberry Pi Screenshot

Tags: raspberry-pi, kivy, screenshot, fullscreen

I am working on a Kivy App for Raspberry Pi. The App runs full screen, not in any kind of windowed mode (which I understand isn't supported on RPi anyway). I am attempting to take screen shots so I can write documentation for the app, but when I take the screen shots in the default manner of pressing the Print Screen button and letting scrot make the image, I find that I see the underlying terminal window through which the GUI is launched instead of the GUI itself.

Is there a trick to getting scrot to recognize the full screen app? Has anyone had success with other screen shot programs for documenting full screen kivy apps?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't the solution I was hoping for, but it works. Since Kivy is cross platform I just ported everything over to a windows machine and ran it there, where I could make my screenshots without issue.